# How do you write test cases for a web server that uses posix sockets?

Tags: webserver, posix, socket, testing

I know how to test it experimentally by running the program, but ideally I would like to test each function I write as I write it.  Usually I can't test my functions until I write a whole bunch of them, and it makes it hard to find out what went wrong.

Does Posix have some way of testing the socket's options, flags, settings, etc, so I can write a test case for a function such as this?

What is the best way to test a function such as this?

```
 /**
 * Creates a listening socket, sets it up with setsockopt, bind, and listen.
 * @param port the port of the listening socket.
 * @return the file descriptor of the listening socket.
 */
int SetUpListeningSocket(int port)
{
    //Variables:
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int s;

    // setup socket address structure
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof (server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // create socket
    s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (!s)
    {
    perror("socket");
    exit(-1);
    }

    // set socket to immediately reuse port when the application closes
    int opt = 1;
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof (opt)) < 0)
    {
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(-1);
    }

    // call bind to associate the socket with our local address and
    // port
    if (bind(s, (const struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof (server)) < 0)
    {
    perror("bind");
    exit(-1);
    }

    // convert the socket to listen for incoming connections
    if (listen(s, SOMAXCONN) < 0)
    {
    perror("listen");
    exit(-1);
    }
    return s;
}
```